# How to use a loop to filter a dataframe, calculate and create a new table in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with several rows of values. I need to filter these rows based on the value of a column (in this case the index column), perform a series of calculations and then return the calculated values to a new table. At the end I need a consolidated table with all the calculated values.

Example:

1. I have the following dataframe:

[image: Database example]

2. First I need to filter all the rows with 1 in the column index
3. Perform some calculation with only these values
4. Store the calculated values into a new table
5. Repeat the process for the rows with 2 in the column index.

Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Can you paste your code?

Comment: What calculations do you want to perform?

Comment: it is a forecast calculation. As each group of items is related to a product I need to analyze them separately and then store into the same table.
-----
final_model = ExponentialSmoothing(df['Values'],trend='mul',seasonal='mul',seasonal_periods=12).fit()
forecast_predictions = final_model.forecast(steps=15)

Answer (score 1):

I can only guess without the actual data and code, but it looks like you need `groupby`+`apply`. You can try:

```
df.groupby('Index')['Values'].apply(lambda s: ExponentialSmoothing(s,trend='mul',seasonal='mul',seasonal_periods=12).fit().forecast(steps=15))
```